# Getting file size with NSURLConnection is very slow

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nshttpurlresponse

I try to get the filesize of a file stored on a server.

I manage to do, but it takes as long as I would download it.

I assume it will download the file to evaluate the size.

Is there a faster way to get the file size?

```
func getFileSizeFromURL(sURL:String) -> String{

    let urlPath: String = sURL;
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)


    var response : NSURLResponse?
    NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request1, returningResponse: &response , error: nil)


    var size:String="";

    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        println(httpResponse.expectedContentLength)


        size="\(httpResponse.expectedContentLength)"

    }

    return size;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume it will download the file to evaluate the size.

Yes, that's because you actually are downloading the file. You should instead use a [HEAD request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) to get just the data about the file. Changing the method from GET or POST to HEAD will get you just the HTTP headers. Insert a line like this after you create `request1`:

```
request1.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"
```

Comment: That helped. Thanks a lot .